# unable to change selections for participant registrations

Tags: civievent, participants

we've just set up our first event in a year and I've just realized it's not possible to change the selections of any participant in the admin backend.

The registration process itself works fine. Participants register through a CiviEvent online registration form in the frontend. But making backend changes to existing registrations isn't possible.

I can view or edit the participant record, and there is a "Change selections" button where I expect it. But when the "Change Selections" is clicked, the "Change Registration Selections" window opens as expected, but there simply is no list of other options shown.  So there are no options to change or select.  The window shows the current selections, then goes right to "Payment Confirmation" section. See below:

[image]

There are no errors in the browser console, and no errors in the ConfigDebug log.  The functionality simply isn't there.

As it's been a while since our last event, and I have made several upgrades since last time, I have no idea when this functionality disappeared; it was working for our event in March 2023. I was hoping this was a version issue, so I've just upgraded to Civi 5.70.0.  But the issue still persists.

System info:
Joomla 3.10
CiviCRM both 5.66.1 and 5.70.0

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ ?

Comment: No, that works fine as petednz mentions below.  I wanted to try on the Joomla demo but that seems to be offline :-(

Comment: Do you have custom tpl or php override or any extension related to priceset/lineitem/participants etc?

Comment: PRADEEP! I think you may have just saved my life.  I had thought about the extensions and had tested with them deactivated.  But I had forgotten about some old custom PHP code.  Removed it, and it seems things are working again!!!!  Would you like to put this in the form of an answer so I can give you the bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's buried in the comments, but I wanted to put a conclusion here -- in the end it was some forgotten custom PHP code that was the culprit.  Thank you Pradeep for the suggestion, sorry I couldn't give you the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

Attempted to replicate on dmaster.

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/participant?reset=1&action=update&id=42&cid=77

[image]

Click through to change selection gives me this url

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/participant/feeselection?reset=1&id=42&cid=77&action=update

and this screen

[image]

is there anything about what I have done that is incorrect, as currently it seems like it does deliver the expected outcome

if the problem on your site cannot be replicated on eg dmaster or one of the other demo sites then perhaps worth using Inspect to see if you can see any console errors

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the procedure I use on my instance. This one used to in the past but somehow doesn't now. Clicking through the change selection button gives me the expected URL (https://DOMAIN.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/participant/feeselection&reset=1&id=3499&cid=315&action=update), but the page that is delivered is just missing the middle section (there aren't even any empty HTML tags marking its absense).  I'm just not even sure where to start troublehshooting this -- no errors in console, nothing in logs.

Comment: FYI I've also tried to reproduce on the Joomla demo, but it seems to be currently offline.

Comment: Further analysis:  I've tested this on another Joomla instance I manage and it's working fine. And I've been able to compare the HTML produced for both screens.  In the broken version, the HTML element fieldset#priceset.priceset-group that should exist between the table.form-layout containing the Participant block and the fieldset#email-receipt block simply isn't there.

Comment: I thought it might be a permissions issue, but I'm testing this with the super admin and ALL CiviCRM CMS permissions are granted. There aren't any Civi ACL permissions.

Comment: Replace the file /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Form/ParticipantFeeSelection.tpl in your non-working installation with the same file from the working installation.

Comment: Great idea Guitarman....unfortunately same behavior with the ParticipantFeeSelection.tpl from the working install :-( It seems that template is just not being called.

Comment: Ok, then the .tpl-file should be complete. Then I'd propose to replace the following files with the ones from your working installation:  /administrator/componente/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ParticipantFeeSelection.php and under the same path the file Participant.php
If this still doesn't help, the block could be hidden via custom CSS?!

Comment: have any changes been made to the price set used for the event since they booked?

Comment: Ah good question petednz, yes I think that's possible -- but I believe items have only been disabled. Would that have an effect?

Comment: Ah I think I see where you're going with this -- line 112 of ParticipantFeeSelection.tpl tests {if $priceSet.fields} to determine if the fieldset#priceset block is displayed.  And obviously that test is failing, but why?

Comment: There is definitely a price set assigned to the event, the same price set it's had since the beginning of registration.

Comment: So I enabled debugging on the broken system and a working one and compared the Smarty Debug output for the request https://domain.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/participant/feeselection&reset=1&id=xx&cid=xx&action=update.  Sure enough, the $priceSet variable exists in the working system output, but is absent in the broken one.  Any ideas why is it being excluded?

Comment: UPDATE: it seems this functionality is essentially broken in this install.  I created a brand new event and a brand new price set, and the Change Selections function STILL excludes the $priceSet.fields.  So it doesn't seem to be a price-set specific issue.  Any ideas where to look now?

Comment: Did you replace the files /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ParticipantFeeSelection.php and Participant.php with the ones from the working installation as suggested?

Comment: I didn't, Guitarman, as I was able to find the answer in some old custom PHP code that had not been removed.  But thank you for your help!

Comment: "it seems this functionality is essentially broken in this install" - are you saying this can be replicated on one of the 'master' sites, eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org